simpleperf stat count / time
I collected simpleperf stats on an Android device like so:
simpleperf stat -e instructions -a --duration 10 --use-devfreq-counters
And the results are:
Performance counter statistics:

#       count  event_name     # count / runtime,  runtime / enabled_time
  421,117,460  instructions   # 1.349 G/sec  (100%)

Total test time: 10.001907 seconds.

My question is: this test ran for 10 seconds. So to get instructions/sec would be a simple matter of dividing 421,117,460 by 10. But why is the "count/runtime" different at 1.349 G/s?

You may want to provide the version of your simpleperf and more information about your Android device.
